# Making a program which will read and write to text files

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, text, text-files

I'm pretty new to Python! I recently started coding a program which I want to write and read to and from text files, while compressing/decompressing sentences (sort of).

However, I've run into a couple problems which I can't seem to fix, basically, I've managed to code the compressing section. But when I go to read the contents of the text file, I'm not sure how to recreate the original sentence through the positions and unique words?!

```
###This section will compress the sentence(s)###
        txt_file = open("User_sentences.txt","wt")
        user_sntnce = input(str("\nPlease enter your sentences you would like compressed."))
        user_sntnce_list = user_sntnce.split(" ")                     
        print(user_sntnce_list)

        for word in user_sntnce_list: 
            if word not in uq_words:
                uq_words.append(word)
        txt_file.write(str(uq_words) + "\n")

        for i in user_sntnce_list:
            positions = int(uq_words.index(i) + 1)
            index.append(positions)
            print(positions)
            print(i)
            txt_file.write(str(positions))
    txt_file.close()
###This section will DECOMPRESS the sentence(s)###
    if GuideChoice == "2":
        txt_file = open("User_sentences.txt","r")
        contents = txt_file.readline()
        words = eval(contents)
        print(words)
        txt_file.close()
```

This is my code so far, it seems to work, however as I've said I'm really stuck, and I really don't know how to move on and recreate the original sentence from the text file.

Comment: When you say _"I really don't know how to..."_, is that meaning you haven't specified how to both compress and expand a sentence ? Could you present algorithm of both functions ?

Comment: Could you define what is `uq_words` ?

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear! Essentially, uq_words will store all the unique words from a sentence, for example "the cat sat on the mat", the unique words from this will be "the, cat, sat on, mat".

Answer (score 0):

From what understand you want to substitute each word in a text file with a word of your choice (a shorter one if you want to "compress"). Meanwhile you keep a "dictionary" (not in the python sense) `uq_words` where you associate each different word with an `index`.
So a sentence "today I like pizza, today is like yesterday" will become:
"12341536".
I tried your code removing `if GuideChoice == "2":` and defining `uq_words=[]` and `index=[]`.
If that's what you intend to do then:

- I imagine you are calling this compression from time to time, it's in a function. So doing what you do in the second line is to open a NEW file with the same name of the previous ones, meaning you will always have the last sentence compressed, loosing the previous.
  Try to read every time the lines, rewrite all and add the new (kinda what you did in `contents = txt_file.readline()`.
- You are printing both the compressed translation (like "2345") AND the array whose component are the words of the splitted sentence. I do not think that is the "compressed" document you are aiming for. Just the "2345" part, right?
  Since, I believe, you want to keep a dictionary, but this code is inside a function, you will loose the dictionary every time the function ends. So write 2 documents: one with the compressed text (every time refreshed and not rewritten!) and another file with 2 columns, where you write the dictionary. You pass the dictionary file name as a string to the function, so you can update it in case new words are added, and you read it as a NX2 array (N the number of words).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! - Very basically, the 'compression' in this instance is I will have a uq_words variable which will contain all the unique words from the sentence which the user inputs, then I also have a positions variable. For example the sentence, "the cat sat on the mat" has unique words of "the, cat, sat, on, mat" and positions will be "123415" so the original sentence can be recreated from the positions variable and uq_words!

Comment: The main problem is: when the dictionary has more than 9 items, how to restore the index if all digits are pasted in a single value ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by this? @J.Piquard

Comment: @JamesStent, if the dictionary contains more than 9 words, the encoded index could be written in one or more digits and how to recognize if `"123245"` is `1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5` or `12, 3, 24, 5` ?